# Can I make "change listener" in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want similiar like Java, or C#. When a Range(1, A).Value was changed, then occurs an method for example Range(1, B).Value be Range(1, A).Value.
I know VBA has Worksheet_Change method, but I use  ComboBox and when I choose an value from Combobox, the change was not occurred.

I'm using a form control, not an ActiveX control.

Comment: It depends on what kind of combo boxes you are using: if you are using form controls then there is no change event for this control and you'll have to keep track of the current value for the combo box somewhere in your file. If you are using ActiveX controls then there is an event handler called `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()` (if the name of your combo box is `ComboBox1`).

Comment: @Comintern as mentioned above, you comment applies only if the OP uses ActiveX components. Otherwise, your approach is not feasible.

Comment: @Comintern yes, you can assign a macro to a from control combo box. Yet, there is only the `click` event for form controls. There is **not** a change event handler for form controls (as your comment seems to indicate with `DropDown1_Change`). The click event occurs **each** time the drop down box is clicked (whether the value is changed or not does not matter). That's not what the OP wants. Hence, your solution works only for ActiveX controls (as written above). Maybe you should try that yourself?

Comment: I have done it multiple times and now again (just because you insisted so much). The click event for form control combo boxes occurs each time the box is clicked and is **not** a direct indication that the value of the combo box has actually changed (Excel 2016 64-bit). Furthermore, if the combo box is linked to a cell and the combo box value is changed via the linked cell then this change is not captured via the macro neither (yet a WorkSheet_Change event handler could capture this). Only with ActiveX combo boxes and the underlying `_Change` event handler such changes are captured.

Comment: @Comintern:  I did say that I verified what I said. So, please refrain from comments such as "my assertions". That's just rude. Also, instead of posting non-constructive comments such as "simply wrong" it would be beneficial to provide any kind of support. Here is a screencast to support my comments: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4436/8qjkxxbt_gif.htm and here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pr29bvbz77pswu/StackOverflow%20Question%2038750798%20changes%20to%20form%20control%20combo%20boxes.xlsm?dl=0 So, please stop posting incorrect / incomplete answers. It's not helping this site.

Comment: @Ralph - The answer isn't incorrect.  It works as exactly described above in my environment.  As far as "helping the site", I'm not sure your attitude is doing much either. I consider this discussion over, and I'll be cleaning up the comments on the OP's post.  I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Thanks answers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the ComboBox, and select Assign Macro...

[image]

It will default to something like "Book1!DropDown1_Change". Click the "New" button.

[image]

It will generate stub code for the event handler, i.e.:

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
    'Put your event handler here.
End Sub
```

Alternately, you can assign an existing macro.

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer! That is working!

Comment: What kind of events of dropdown are?

Comment: @Pisti - Unfortunately form controls only get the one event that can be assigned using the method above. ActiveX controls have more.

Comment: Aha, and what are different ActiveXs and Form Controls?

Comment: @Pisti - You should be able to see both types on the ribbon. Look it Developer -> Insert.  The Form Controls should be on the top, and the ActiveX ones on the bottom.  The Form Controls are basically severely stripped down versions of the ActiveX ones - those are basically the same ones you would use on a UserForm.